# LuaLaTeX: mkluatexfontdb does not include Type-1-fonts ( = *.pfb-files)

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload, type1

I'm running texlive 2011 on a Linux machine. Years ago I bought some Type 1 fonts, namely Rotis. They have been installed properly and Libre Office e.g. can print them.

But running `mkluatexfontdb -v > fontlog` logs no Rotis, under whatever name. No `*.pfb` file neither.

So how do I use those Type 1 fonts under LuaLaTeX? I checked the `fontspec`-manual, but no hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luaotfload currently does not work with type1 fonts. A patch is on the way and future releases will include support for these fonts. For now, you have to use the old TeX way and create tfms (with all the drawbacks).

Comment: Quickest answer ever, unfortunately negativ. When will this patch appear in luatex? 0.72 ?

Comment: @KeksDose LuaTeX is already capable of using Type1 fonts. Its a matter of the font loader, the most popular one in the plain and LaTeX world is Luaotfload. I have no idea about the release schedule, but I think the next or the second next major update will have it, which automatically get into texlive (and MikTeX?).

Comment: Using the font with tfm's and installed "in the old way" has no real drawbacks - it is only not so easy to get working. But it would have the *advantage* that is works even if the font is old and uses unusual glyph names, and that the font will work with pdftex too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if I am right, a tfm has only at most 256 glyphs. A Type 1 font can have more. So you need some kind of mapping to access all the glyphs.

Comment: I should mention that all the credit for the patch (and for very much work on Luaotfload) should go to @KhaledHosny .

Comment: Yes a tfm can have only 256 glyphs and a type1 font can have more. But can you access the unencoded glyphs of a type1 font with xelatex without using tfm and enc-files? E.g. the utopia font has - if one looks in the afm - the glyphs for ograve and copyright. But you don't get them with `\font\test="putb8a.pfb" \test abc ©ò`. Only the abc appears.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then it's a XeTeX bug, I'd say. It is definitely possible with LuaTeX (just tried).

Answer (score 3):

you can try to convert your Type 1 font into an otf type, for example with fontforge.

Comment: I've been using the metrics of W.A. Schmidt for years, if I remember correctly, either you or Ulrike had a hand on dctt, when I got stuck. I just wondered how to do it with Luatex.